# Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ constitute a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces

**Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ constitute a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?**

**[Here, $x = (\xi_1 \xi_2 \xi_3)$]**

**(a) All $x$ with $\xi_1 =\xi_2$ and $\xi_3=0$.**

**(b) All $x$ with $\xi_1=\xi_2+1$.**

**(c) All $x$ with positive $\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3$.**

**(d) All $x$ with $\xi_1-\xi_2+\xi_3=k$ const.**

I have thought about the following:

For (a), denote by $M$ the space generated by these characteristics and take $(x,x,0), (y,y,0)\in M$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, with which $a(x,x,0)+b(y,y,0)=(ax+by, ax+by, 0)$ and thus $a(x,x,0)+b(y,y,0)\in M$, then $M$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

For (b), denote by $M$ the space generated by these characteristics and take $(x_1,x_1-1,x_3), (y_1,y_1-1,y_3)\in M$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, with which $a(x_1,x_1-1,x_3)+b(y_1,y_1-1,y_3)=(ax_1+by_1, ax_1+by_1-(a+b), ax_3+by_3)$ and thus $a(x_1,x_1-1,x_3)+b(y_1,y_1-1,y_3)\notin M$, then $M$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

For (c), denote by $M$ the space generated by these characteristics and take $(x_1,x_2,x_3), (y_1,y_2,y_3)\in M$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<0$ and $b<0$, with which $a(x_1,x_2,x_3)+b(y_1,y_2,y_3)=(ax_1+by_1, ax_2+by_2, ax_3+by_3)$ and thus $a(x_1,x_2,x_3)+b(y_1,y_2,y_3)\notin M$, then $M$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

For (d), denote by $M$ the space generated by these characteristics and take $(x_1,x_2,x_3), (y_1,y_2,y_3)\in M$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, with which $a(x_1,x_2,x_3)+b(y_1,y_2,y_3)=(ax_1+by_1, ax_2+by_2, ax_3+by_3)$ and so $ax_1+by_1-(ax_2+by_2)+ax_3+by_3=a(x_1-x_2+x_3)+b(y_1-y_2+y_3)=ac_1+bc_2=k$ const and thus $a(x_1,x_2,x_3)+b(y_1,y_2,y_3)\in M$, then $M$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: (a) is a subspace and your proof is fine.  (b) and (c) are both not subspaces, and a much shorter proof would be that they do not contain the zero vector $(0,0,0)$, but your proofs are fine (*even if wordy*).  (d) is *not* a subspace *unless* $k=0$.  For any other $k$ it will not be, again by looking at the zero vector.

Comment: @JMoravitz Where does the test I did in (d) fail?

Comment: My interpretation is that $\zeta_1-\zeta_2+\zeta_3$ must equal a very specific $k$, each and every time.  E.g. if $k=2$ then we would need $\zeta_1-\zeta_2+\zeta_3=2$.  You made it to $a(x_1-x_2+x_3)+b(y_1-y_2+y_3)$ which simplifies to $ak+bk=(a+b)k$ which is explicitly *not* equal to $k$ unless $a+b=1$ or unless $k=0$.  We cannot guarantee that $a+b=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only (a) is a subspace, (d) is a subspace only if k=0 otherwise it doesn’t contain $\vec 0$ which is the most important one. Such argument on $\vec 0$ allow to classify not true also (b) and (c).

Indeed for a subspace all the following three properties must be satisfied:

$$1) \ \vec{0} \in W\\
2) \ \vec{v}+\vec{w} \in W\\
3) \ \vec{cv}\to c \cdot \vec{v} \ ,c \in \mathbb{R}$$

thus if a subset do not contain $\vec0$, it is sufficient to conclude that it is not a subspace, this is really the most simple and first check to do.

EG

in $\mathbb{R^3}$ the only possible subset are: $\vec{0}$, the line planes throughout the origin and  $\mathbb{R^3}$ itself